# Rails resend email activation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I am having trouble setting up a resend activation email. When the user creates an account the email sends perfectly, but when they try to resend the activation email I am getting and error. Thanks in advance for all the help.

**This is the error**

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Sessions#resend_activation
>
> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations",
>   :  email=>"TestEmail@gmail.com", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched
>   constraints: [:id]

This is the line its highlighting in account_activation.html.erb

```
<%= link_to edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) do %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]

get '/resend_page', to: 'sessions#resend_account_activation_page'
post 'resend_activation', to: 'sessions#resend_activation'
```

**resend_account_activation_page.html.erb**

```
  <div class="FormBody">
      <h1 style="margin-bottom:30px">Account Activation</h1>

      <p> If you need the activation email to be resent enter the email you signed up with and hit the resend button. </p>
        <%= form_for(:sessions, url: resend_activation_path) do |f| %>

          <div>
              <%= f.text_field :email, class: "Input", placeholder: "Email"%>
          </div>

           <%= f.submit "Resend", class: "SignUpButton", data: {toggle: "tooltip"}, title: "Resend" %>
       <% end %>
    </div>
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
  def resend_activation
    if  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:sessions][:email])
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:success] = "Activation email resent!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Email is not asociated with any account, please sign up first.'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
  def activate
    update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end
```

**account_activations_controller.rb**

```
  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
def account_activation(user)
  @user = user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Account Activation"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out I forgot I had to call the create_activation_digest before I sent out the email so it creates a new token. Thanks for the help!

```
def create_activation_digest
  self.activation_token  = User.new_token
  self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  update_columns(activation_digest: User.digest(activation_token))   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`edit_account_activation_url` in `account_activation.html.erb` expects a user id, so you should probably change it for:

```
<%= link_to edit_account_activation_url(@user.id) do %>
```

And then you can retrieve the user in your `account_activations_controller.rb` with the id:

```
  def edit
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```